# How to convert a str into a bs4.element.Tag after I turned bs4.element.Tag into a string?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I webscraped a website and I got some `bs4.element.Tag`. Then I turned them into a strings with the following function:

```
ppp = []
for x in pp:
            ppp.append(str(x))

# where pp is a list of `bs4.element.Tag` elements:
# eg: [<div class="title"><a href="/press/key/date/2004/html/sp040621.de.html" lang="fixed">Gertrude Tumpel-Gugerell: Presentation, delivered at the symposium "Zahlungsverkehr in Deutschland im Umfeld europäischer und internationaler Entwicklungen" oganised by the Deutsche Bundesbank in Frankfurt am Main, pdf 320 kB</a></div>,
 <div class="title"><a href="/press/key/date/2004/html/sp040614.en.html">Jean-Claude Trichet: The International Financial Architecture - Where do we stand?</a></div>,
 <div class="title"><a href="/press/key/date/2004/html/sp040610.en.html">Otmar Issing: On the primacy of price stability</a></div>]
```

Now I would like to turn each element of my list back to a `bs4.element.Tag`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Just use `x` within your `for` loop...

Comment: Ah issue being I removed some items from `x`, that's why I turned it into string in the first place. But maybe I can tease out the difference between `x` and `ppp`

Comment: Does `ppp` *need* to be composed of strings, vs call `str()` on the elements when you need to use them? Please post a [mre].

Comment: yes it needs to be strings as I need to run some code to remove some elements from it

Comment: The duplicate I just tagged explains how to create new `Tag` elements.